# Not able to select item from dropdown using selenium webdriver for vba

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to automatically select the first option from a dropdown in a webpage by using selenium webdriver for vba but unable to do so. I have tried using different methods like find element by ID, find element by xpath etc. but getting NoSuchElementError.

Here is the code which I have tried.

```
bot.FindElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04").Click
```

here is the HTML code for the element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the whole HTML code of the web page.

```
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: auto;">
  <form id="ReportViewerForm" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" action="./ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMPM%2fMPM_ProjectServices_Schedule" method="post">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="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">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ReportViewerForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ReportViewerForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/ReportServer/WebResource.axd?d=9xs5IOIfHw061TI0iHfRtCwcwm-Hj_q-6nrNp49wBW4ITTDIgspL_7LVbElrrTLYqCLVjoZNUhMNPIuGvaFRYw4C2NbxxS79dLaHu03gifA1&amp;t=637100682046795651" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ReportServer/ScriptResource.axd?d=rk4cQgE67-CFfPE2bk9TbF_e_pYPZ5Fy_vkGwRwoX5kyz2YOoqnm25wmjRq4HmptTWVP1ULqYBrE4HHK-M3T7oBdrEWrJmxRhtlT9GbkJ79fFOP6HC8nzRVpzGlPfqlt_M1axvx-GXQ4M61ubN1d8G-JHeYRmdfdWkz6GkwbsSs1&amp;t=ffffffffecf19baa" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ReportServer/ScriptResource.axd?d=jke1BTXXkzpx8QyDNk5MBiwVYnFwjyMgzINrp_oXCpsBkko99HnDr_rzrNzvHzyAK0PVFrKABrFWK2A1cbJGAJbwkSwrXJvC58YVxf1fRHELz28rRMUg7_2CTjGPKJGz9CX-d_sSPpCNu_L1MCfcx0n5LMLmxXZvpfRgYnHZscD5sc4_hs3mrssMm0HwH86i0&amp;t=ffffffffecf19baa" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.BrowserNavigationCorrector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=ViewerScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ReportServer/ScriptResource.axd?d=Fu_zv7h1Rznnc_ZLFNjT_Rl-wO7fB-KT_fBurCijvyrOMaFdirVDY9f7YXWFS9ztJmFsSywt6hVjNzhGPBxcy8ngfF6wmT3RlOVFYhrfgLCjbMZghFZSluNhGZuZMv2RUdvGMP0YFyGxyUTl8OPevvG_yMfV4QGjvLKS3jVKjiQ1&amp;t=ffffffffecf19baa" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" type="hidden" value="177045DE">
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('AjaxScriptManager', 'ReportViewerForm', ['tNavigationCorrector$ctl00','NavigationCorrector_ctl00','fReportViewerControl$ReportViewer','','fReportViewerControl$DocMap','','fReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportArea',''], ['NavigationCorrector','NavigationCorrector'], ['ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl00',''], 0, '');
//]]>
</script>

    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr height="100%"><td width="100%">
   <span><span id="ctl01_ctl00" style="display: none;"></span><script>

$addHandler(window, 'beforeunload', function() {Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().abortPostBack();});

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() !== null) {
        var label = $get('ctl01_ctl00');
        label.style.display = '';
        label.innerText = args.get_error().message;
        label.textContent = label.innerText;
    }
});

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function(sender, args) {$get('ctl01_ctl00').style.display = 'none';});

</script></span><div id="NavigationCorrector" style="display: none;">
    <input name="NavigationCorrector$ScrollPosition" id="NavigationCorrector_ScrollPosition" type="hidden"><input name="NavigationCorrector$ViewState" id="NavigationCorrector_ViewState" type="hidden"><input name="NavigationCorrector$PageState" id="NavigationCorrector_PageState" type="hidden" value="Loaded"><div id="NavigationCorrector_ctl00">
        <input name="NavigationCorrector$NewViewState" id="NavigationCorrector_NewViewState" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div><noscript>
    &amp;nbsp;Browser settings prevent scripts from running on this report. To view this report without scripts, click&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href="/reportserver?%2fMPM%2fMPM_ProjectServices_Schedule&amp;amp;rs:Command=Render&amp;amp;rs:Format=HTML5&amp;amp;rc:LinkTarget=_top&amp;amp;rc:Javascript=false&amp;amp;rc:Toolbar=false"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;
</noscript><div id="ReportViewerControl_ReportViewer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="ReportViewerControl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" onclick="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();">
        <div id="ReportViewerControl_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage" style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid red; overflow: auto; font-size: 0.85em; display: none;">
            <h2>
                Report Viewer Configuration Error
            </h2><p>The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add &lt;add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebServer, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /&gt; to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add &lt;add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebServer, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /&gt; to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.</p>
        </div><span id="ReportViewerControl_ctl03"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl00" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl03_ctl00" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl01" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl03_ctl01" type="hidden"></span><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl10" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl10" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl11" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl11" type="hidden" value="standards"><div id="ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.7; background-color: white;">

        </div><div class="WaitControlBackground" id="ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1001;">
            <table height="100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="32" height="32"><img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" alt="Loading..." src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SpinningWheel.gif"></td><td class="WaitInfoCell"><span class="WaitText">Loading...</span><div class="CancelLinkDiv">
                        <a class="CancelLinkText" href="javascript:$get('ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait').control._cancelCurrentPostback();">Cancel</a>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div><input name="ReportViewerControl$AsyncWait$HiddenCancelField" id="ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_HiddenCancelField" type="hidden" value="False"><table id="ReportViewerControl_fixedTable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr class="MenuBarBkGnd">
                <td style="width: 25%; display: none;"></td><td style="width: 6px; display: none;"></td><td style="width: 100%;"></td>
            </tr><tr id="ParametersRowReportViewerControl">
                <td colspan="3"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04" style="width: 100%; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <div onclick="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();">
                        <table width="100%" class="ParametersFrame ParamsGrid MenuBarBkGnd" id="ParameterTable_ReportViewerControl_ctl04" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" name="ParameterTable_ReportViewerControl_ctl04">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="100%"><table id="ParametersGridReportViewerControl_ctl04">
                                    <tbody><tr isparameterrow="true">
                                        <td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue"><span>BU</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right: 0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03" data-parametername="BU">
                                            <div style="white-space: nowrap;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;">
                                                <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue" class="null" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue" type="text" size="28" readonly="readonly"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$ddDropDownButton" title="Select a value" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton" style="margin-top: 1px; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer;" type="image" alt="Select a value" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.MultiValueSelect.gif">
                                            </div>
                                        </div></td><td class="InterParamPadding"></td><td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue"><span>Phase</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right: 0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05" data-parametername="Phase">
                                            <div style="white-space: nowrap;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;">
                                                <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue" class="null" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue" type="text" size="28" readonly="readonly"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$ddDropDownButton" title="Select a value" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ddDropDownButton" style="margin-top: 1px; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer;" type="image" alt="Select a value" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.MultiValueSelect.gif">
                                            </div>
                                        </div></td><td class="InterParamPadding"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table></td><td width="6"></td><td class="SubmitButtonCell"><table>
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl00" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00" type="submit" value="View Report"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table><input disabled="disabled" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div><iframe name="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ctl01" title="BU place holder" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ctl01" src="javascript:'';" frameborder="0" longdesc="BU place holder" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 10;" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;"></iframe><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown" style="border: 1px solid darkgray; height: 150px; overflow: auto; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 11; background-color: window;" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;">
                    <span><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl01$HiddenIndices" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl01_HiddenIndices" type="hidden" value=""></span>
                </div><iframe name="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ctl01" title="Phase place holder" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ctl01" src="javascript:'';" frameborder="0" longdesc="Phase place holder" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 10;" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;"></iframe><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_divDropDown" style="border: 1px solid darkgray; height: 150px; overflow: auto; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 11; background-color: window;" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;">
                    <span><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$divDropDown$ctl01$HiddenIndices" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_divDropDown_ctl01_HiddenIndices" type="hidden" value=""></span>
                </div></td>
            </tr><tr style="height: 6px; font-size: 2pt;">
                <td class="SplitterNormal" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; cursor: default;" colspan="3"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ToggleParam">
                    <input name="ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$img" title="Hide Parameters" align="middle" id="ReportViewerControl_ToggleParam_img" aria-live="polite" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="void(0);" type="image" alt="Hide Parameters" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizCollapse.png"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$store" id="ReportViewerControl_ToggleParam_store" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$collapse" id="ReportViewerControl_ToggleParam_collapse" type="hidden" value="false">
                </div></td>
            </tr><tr style="display: none;">

            </tr><tr>
                <td style="width: 25%; height: 100%; vertical-align: top; display: none;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div id="ReportViewerControl_DocMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl08" style="display: none;">
                            <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl08$ClientClickedId" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl08_ClientClickedId" type="hidden">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></td><td class="SplitterNormal" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 4px; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl07">
                    <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl07$img" title="Hide Document Map" align="top" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl07_img" aria-live="polite" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="void(0);" type="image" alt="Hide Document Map" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterVertCollapse.png"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl07$store" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl07_store" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl07$collapse" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl07_collapse" type="hidden" value="false">
                </div></td><td style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09" style="width: 100%; height: 247.27px; overflow: auto; position: relative;">
                    <div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_ctl09" role="main" style="display: none;"></div><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ReportArea">
                        <div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_VisibilityState" fornonreportcontentarea="false" newcontenttype="ReportingServices.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.None">
                            <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00" type="hidden" value="None">
                        </div><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ScrollPosition" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ScrollPosition" type="hidden"><span id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget"></span><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ReportControl" style="display: none;">
                            <span></span><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03" type="hidden"><input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ReportControl_ctl04" type="hidden" value="100">
                        </div><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_NonReportContent" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: seems to be `ReportViewerControl_ctxxx` the last part is dynamic. And does the options show once you click on the listbox, if so hen check if there is a dynamic div loads with options.

Comment: does that mean I cannot work with the FindElementByID method to select the option inside the dropdown? I am not sure how to check whether its dynamic or not. I will inspect the element for the first option and put it here. Just see if you can make out anything from it.

Comment: @supputuri I have added the HTML code for the first option which I want to select. I hope it helps you to understand it better.

Comment: After doing some more research I found that it has an iframe as well. Does it in any way causing the error? I am not at all familiar with iframe and how it works. Anybody had any idea and would like to help are most welcome.

Comment: If the element is present in the iframe, you have to switch to iframe using `driver.switch_to_frame('iframe_id/iframe_name')`. Make sure you switch to default window one you are done with the operation on the iframe.

Comment: I have changed the image of the code to the actual code.